# Will cats remember me after 4 months?

Tags: cats

To start, I am a cat person (really love them and thank god for creating cats). I had winter break from December 20 (2017) to January 28 (2018). Spring semester started January 29. Decided to spend the break at my parents country to visit my grandma and uncle. December 30 I bought 2 kittens (one male, one female) and grandma suggested to have them placed in one room and not get out. During the month together with the kittens, I spent the most time with them, while my grandma just feed them and don’t interact with them at all. At least 5 days a week, I would spend 30-45 minutes with them, playing or just being around together. So I believe the kittens recognized me WAY MORE then either my grandma or uncle. As my break got closer to an end, the kittens started going outdoors wandering around (we stayed at a big house with outdoors). Then, I had to come back home for college. So during the stay, my grandma most likely saw the cats for only 30 minutes (1 minutes each day), while I saw and spent time with them for 700 minutes. And me and the kittens drew very close as the month passed. I won’t see them again until the end of May (4 months), and probably will be cats at that time. Will they remember me, knowing that they knew me a lot better, or will 4 months be enough for the cats/kittens to forget about me? The fact that I left them as kittens makes me doubt they will remember me, but I want to be sure.

Please, I need serious answers. Since I’m a cat person, I got very emotional in the final days with the kittens. I really want them to remember me.